# Dan Abramov's theme change logic

Tags: javascript, gatsby

Can you explain how this `window.__onThemeChange` function works?
I was trying to implement Dan Abramov's way to aproach setting a dark mode in gatsby app but i don't get how above function works.
First it is definded and called from within `setTheme()` with `newTheme` as argument.

```
(function () {
  window.__onThemeChange = function () { };
  function setTheme (newTheme) {
    window.__theme = newTheme;
    preferredTheme = newTheme;
    document.body.className = newTheme;
    window.__onThemeChange(newTheme);
  }
  var preferredTheme;
  try {
    preferredTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  } catch (err) { }
  window.__setPreferredTheme = function (newTheme) {
    setTheme(newTheme);
    try {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    } catch (err) { }
  }
  var darkQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  darkQuery.addListener(function (e) {
    window.__setPreferredTheme(e.matches ? 'dark' : 'light')
  });
  setTheme(preferredTheme || (darkQuery.matches ? 'dark' : 'light'));
})();
```

Then this function is used in Component's to set state:

```
    class Layout extends React.Component {
      state = {
        theme: null,
      };
      componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ theme: window.__theme });
        window.__onThemeChange = () => {
          this.setState({ theme: window.__theme });
        };
      }
```

This `window.__onThemeChange` function is just defined, then called without body just using an argument of `newTheme` and then redefined in Component as a way to change state.
Link to Dan's repo:

File where is is defined:
https://github.com/gaearon/overreacted.io/blob/master/src/html.js

Component:
https://github.com/gaearon/overreacted.io/blob/master/src/components/Layout.js

Comment: I am pretty sure he's just using a `gatsby-blog-starter` - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog/ & https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/ - so it's not something that's "Dan Abramov's blog"-specific

Comment: Acutally, this dark-mode-plugin is using Dan's implementation. So it is something he wrote himself.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out.The `window.__onThemeChange` is defined in html.js  (which is global file) without its body and then this body is defined inside Layout component(to connect with state of this component) and then called again from html.js. The way Dan figure it out is amazing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as legacy code and probably solves certain problems you're not going to have in Gatsby. Why not toggling a CSS class on the document body?

Comment: eg. the style, using `var` and no arrow functions

Comment: CSS class is not enought. I want to have a anchor to OS theme preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much use react hooks whitin gatsby with a simple import as shown [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/gatsbyjs-react-hooks-gatsby).

A hook for this job could be [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

An approach i would use, is setting a CSS class dinamically depending on a 'global' state provided by useContext and binding the switch mode button to this context.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the argument `newTheme` is not used in the `window.__onThemeChange` function. Instead, the function is defined in the `Layout` component to work with `window.__theme`. The argument can be deleted and it will still work (as shown below).

```js
(function () {
  window.__onThemeChange = function () { }; // Function was actually defined without arguments
  function setTheme (newTheme) {
    window.__theme = newTheme;
    preferredTheme = newTheme;
    document.body.className = newTheme;
    window.__onThemeChange(); // Called without newTheme
  }
  var preferredTheme;
  try {
    preferredTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  } catch (err) { }
  window.__setPreferredTheme = function (newTheme) {
    setTheme(newTheme);
    try {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    } catch (err) { }
  }
  var darkQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
  darkQuery.addListener(function (e) {
    window.__setPreferredTheme(e.matches ? 'dark' : 'light')
  });
  setTheme(preferredTheme || (darkQuery.matches ? 'dark' : 'light'));
})();
```

So basically, `window.__onThemeChange` is defined globally in `html.js` as an empty function and called in the `setTheme` function.

When the `Layout` component mounts, it connects the component state with the `window.__onThemeChange` function by providing it a body with a call to `this.setState` and an argumet of `{ theme: window.__theme }` (ignoring the passed in `newTheme` argument from `html.js`).

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ theme: window.__theme }); // set the theme to the theme currently stored in window.__theme
    window.__onThemeChange = () => { 
      this.setState({ theme: window.__theme });
    }; // assign a function to window.__onThemeChange that "subscribes" this component to changes in the theme.
  }
```

So whenever `window.__setPreferredTheme` is called, `setTheme` is also called which in turn calls `window.__onThemeChange`.

```js
  onChange={e =>
    window.__setPreferredTheme(
      e.target.checked ? 'dark' : 'light'
    )} // Call to window.__setPrefferedTheme

  window.__setPreferredTheme = function(newTheme) {
    setTheme(newTheme); // setTheme is called as a consequence
    try {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
    } catch (err) {}}

  function setTheme(newTheme) {
    window.__theme = newTheme;
    preferredTheme = newTheme;
    document.body.className = newTheme;
    window.__onThemeChange(newTheme); // Which in turn calls onThemeChange. Remember, the newTheme argument should not be passed.
  }
```

Some brilliant pub-sub architectural thinking.